# Istio Origin Authorization Based on JWT Claims

Tags: jwt, istio

How can I make authorization decisions based on claims in the JWT when using an Istio JWT [OriginAuthenticationMethod](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.authentication.v1alpha1/#OriginAuthenticationMethod) Policy?

Comment: Could you be more specific. Do you have any additional requirement? Or you just looking for instructions?

Comment: I'm primarily trying to understand if there is any sort of built-in capability in Istio to allow making authorization decisions based on JWT claims.  If this is not supported directly, an pointers to how we could extend the functionality to support this type of use case would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look through Istio -> Concepts -> Security?

There is an example under [ServiceRoleBinding](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#servicerolebinding) that might be what your looking for.

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-binding-products
  namespace: default
spec:
  subjects:
    properties:
      request.auth.claims[email]: "a@foo.com"
  roleRef:
    kind: ServiceRole
    name: "products-viewer"
```